# How can I prevent wireless network interference?

Tags: wireless-networking, interference

One of my family members uses an Apple iPod Touch 5th gen which, according to [Apple's website](http://www.apple.com/ipod-touch/specs.html),

has the following wireless specifications:

> 802.11a/b/g/n Wi-Fi (802.11n 2.4GHz and 5GHz)

My LAN has a [Linksys EA6500 (AC1750) router](http://www.linksys.com/en-eu/products/routers/EA6500) for the gateway.

When I game, I use a [Turtle Beach X41 headset](http://www.turtlebeach.com/product-detail/headsets-legacy/ear-force-x41/240) which has the following wireless specifications:

> Digital Wireless RF wireless carrier reception: 2.404-2.476GHz

Whenever the iPod is turned on and connected to the wireless network, it creates static noise in my headset. This also happens if someone is watching, say, Netflix on the TV and they are using wireless to stream (instead of an Ethernet cable plugged into the RJ-45 port on the back of the TV). So, it's not only the iPod that **can** cause this, but we don't watch Netflix anymore, so it is only the iPod for the time being.

How can I prevent this interference from occurring? It's so annoying that I have to sometimes disable the wireless network connection for the iPod.

Comment: there probably isn't a practical solution to this issue, other than to try to get your wifi devices to use the 5ghz band when possible, and move them away from your headset (in another room at least) if you cannot.

Comment: How can I get the iPod to use the 5 GHz band instead of the 2.4GHz? This happens even when the iPod is being used in the bedroom and I am gaming in the living room area (at computer desk). It's an apartment, so that's pretty much the maximum separation we can achieve.